# Consulta Xpath con espacio de nombres

Tags: xpath

Estoy dándole vueltas y buscando info en internet pero no encuentro nada.
Como puedo montar una consulta Xpath para seleccionar por ejemplo  el nodo **dom:gestor**
Estoy utilizando para hacer pruebas BaseX Gui, si cargo algun Xml sin espacios de nombre, no hay problema, pero este que tiene un espacio de nombres, no doy con la tecla.
Ayuda pleases!!!.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale me contesto yo.

Si queremos seleccionar el nodo gestor
//*[local-name()='gestor']

si ademas tenemos mas de un nodo gestor y queremos seleccionar solo cuyo idioma es 'es'
//*[local-name()='gestor'][*[local-name()='idioma' and text()='es']]

Y si ademas solo queremos seleccionarsu nif
//*[local-name()='gestor'][*[local-name()='idioma' and text()='es']]/*[local-name()='nif']